# sql get newest date and price of all inventory_items

Tags: sql, date, max, where-clause

I have this sql tables, and i need to get from all inventory items the newest date from table: orders with the price paid on this date

```
table:orders
id
date

table:order_items
order_id
inventory_id
price

table:inventory
item_number
```

if i do something like that:

```
SELECT inventory.item_number, orders.date, order_items.price
FROM inventory
INNER JOIN order_items ON inventory.id = order_items.inventory_id
INNER JOIN orders ON order_items.order_id = orders.id
WHERE max(orders.date)
```

it's not working, and i get an error.
What is the correct way to do that

Comment: Lookup the `GROUP BY`clause, then you can get the maximum date for each grouped item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `where` clause, but the `MAX()` cannot go there directly.  Try a subquery:

```
SELECT i.item_number, o.date, orders.price
FROM inventory i INNER JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON i.id = oi.inventory_id INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON oi.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.date = (SELECt max(o2.date) FROM orders o2);
```